# Query using index or not (apparently) depending on table size

Tags: postgresql, indexing, query-optimization, timescaledb

I have a table storing timeseries of weather data.

```
                           Table « public.weather_data »
   Colonne   |           Type           | Collationnement | NULL-able | Par défaut 
-------------+--------------------------+-----------------+-----------+------------
 timestamp   | timestamp with time zone |                 | not null  | 
 location_id | integer                  |                 | not null  | 
 type_id     | integer                  |                 | not null  | 
 value       | double precision         |                 |           | 
Index :
    "weather_data_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (location_id, "timestamp", type_id)
Contraintes de clés étrangères :
    "weather_data_location_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (location_id) REFERENCES locations(id)
    "weather_data_type_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (type_id) REFERENCES weather_data_types(id)
Triggers :
    ts_insert_blocker BEFORE INSERT ON weather_data FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE _timescaledb_internal.insert_blocker()
```

I want to query values for a location and a type in a time interval.

In my development environment, with a small amount of data

```
SELECT * FROM hypertable_detailed_size('weather_data');
 table_bytes | index_bytes | toast_bytes | total_bytes | node_name 
-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------
    12902400 |     9887744 |           0 |    22790144 |
```

the query uses the index

```
EXPLAIN SELECT weather_data.timestamp AS anon_1, weather_data.value AS weather_data_value FROM weather_data WHERE 31 = weather_data.location_id AND weather_data.timestamp >= '2000-01-01' AND weather_data.timestamp < '2020-02-02' AND weather_data.type_id = 1 ORDER BY weather_data.timestamp;
```

```
 Custom Scan (ChunkAppend) on weather_data  (cost=0.28..100.10 rows=53 width=16)
   Order: weather_data."timestamp"
   ->  Index Scan using "7790_23369_weather_data_pkey" on _hyper_49_7790_chunk  (cost=0.28..1.88 rows=1 width=16)
         Index Cond: ((31 = location_id) AND ("timestamp" >= '2000-01-01 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone) AND ("timestamp" < '2020-02-02 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone) AND (type_id = 1))
   ->  Index Scan using "7791_23372_weather_data_pkey" on _hyper_49_7791_chunk  (cost=0.28..1.89 rows=1 width=16)
         Index Cond: ((31 = location_id) AND ("timestamp" >= '2000-01-01 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone) AND ("timestamp" < '2020-02-02 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone) AND (type_id = 1))
   [...]
```

In my production environment, where much more data is stored

```
SELECT * FROM hypertable_detailed_size('weather_data');
 table_bytes | index_bytes | toast_bytes | total_bytes | node_name 
-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------
 24146182144 | 34957369344 |           0 | 59103551488 |
```

the index doesn't seem to be used.

```
 Sort  (cost=835599.15..836053.40 rows=181699 width=16)
   Sort Key: _hyper_1_33_chunk."timestamp"
   ->  Append  (cost=157.08..816618.66 rows=181699 width=16)
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on _hyper_1_33_chunk  (cost=157.08..560.33 rows=124 width=16)
               Recheck Cond: ((31 = location_id) AND ("timestamp" >= '2000-01-01 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone) AND ("timestamp" < '2020-02-02 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone) AND (type_id = 1))
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on "33_98_weather_data_pkey"  (cost=0.00..157.05 rows=124 width=0)
                     Index Cond: ((31 = location_id) AND ("timestamp" >= '2000-01-01 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone) AND ("timestamp" < '2020-02-02 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone) AND (type_id = 1))
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on _hyper_1_34_chunk  (cost=263.76..878.92 rows=198 width=16)
               Recheck Cond: ((31 = location_id) AND ("timestamp" >= '2000-01-01 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone) AND ("timestamp" < '2020-02-02 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone) AND (type_id = 1))
         [...]
```

The only difference I can think of is the amount of data.

Could there be something else?

I understand there can be trade-offs leading the engine not to use an index if the query may be faster another way, but here it doesn't seem to be the case.

---

I tried to add a new index to match the query even more.

```
                           Table « public.weather_data »
   Colonne   |           Type           | Collationnement | NULL-able | Par défaut 
-------------+--------------------------+-----------------+-----------+------------
 timestamp   | timestamp with time zone |                 | not null  | 
 location_id | integer                  |                 | not null  | 
 type_id     | integer                  |                 | not null  | 
 value       | double precision         |                 |           | 
Index :
    "weather_data_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (location_id, "timestamp", type_id)
    "weather_data_location_id_type_id_timestamp_idx" UNIQUE, btree (location_id, type_id, "timestamp")
```

Obviously, the index size grows bigger:

```
SELECT * FROM hypertable_detailed_size('weather_data');
 table_bytes | index_bytes | toast_bytes | total_bytes | node_name 
-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------
 24146182144 | 49657004032 |           0 | 73803186176 |
```

and it seems this index doesn't help that much.

```
 Sort  (cost=604117.07..604571.26 rows=181676 width=16)
   Sort Key: _hyper_1_33_chunk."timestamp"
   ->  Append  (cost=6.31..585138.76 rows=181676 width=16)
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on _hyper_1_33_chunk  (cost=6.31..409.57 rows=124 width=16)
               Recheck Cond: ((31 = location_id) AND (type_id = 1) AND ("timestamp" >= '2000-01-01 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone) AND ("timestamp" < '2020-02-02 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone))
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on _hyper_1_33_chunk_weather_data_location_id_type_id_timestamp_id  (cost=0.00..6.28 rows=124 width=0)
                     Index Cond: ((31 = location_id) AND (type_id = 1) AND ("timestamp" >= '2000-01-01 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone) AND ("timestamp" < '2020-02-02 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone))
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on _hyper_1_34_chunk  (cost=7.44..622.60 rows=198 width=16)
               Recheck Cond: ((31 = location_id) AND (type_id = 1) AND ("timestamp" >= '2000-01-01 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone) AND ("timestamp" < '2020-02-02 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone))
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on _hyper_1_34_chunk_weather_data_location_id_type_id_timestamp_id  (cost=0.00..7.39 rows=198 width=0)
                     Index Cond: ((31 = location_id) AND (type_id = 1) AND ("timestamp" >= '2000-01-01 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone) AND ("timestamp" < '2020-02-02 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone))
```

Any idea why the index doesn't allow a fast query in my production environment and what I can do about it?

---

**Edit**: `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`. Also Fixing queries to ensure both databases return the same data. In my queries above, the prod DB would return more data (in fact, the dev DB would return no data). Now querying one full year of hourly data (i.e. 8760 rows).

Development:

```
 Custom Scan (ChunkAppend) on weather_data  (cost=0.42..36800.07 rows=9371 width=16) (actual time=0.033..11.025 rows=8760 loops=1)
   Order: weather_data."timestamp"
   Buffers: shared hit=1672
   ->  Index Scan using _hyper_1_137_chunk_weather_data_location_id_type_id_timestamp_i on _hyper_1_137_chunk  (cost=0.42..225.73 rows=55 width=16) (actual time=0.031..0.078 rows=49 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ((32 = location_id) AND (type_id = 1) AND ("timestamp" >= '2002-01-01 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone) AND ("timestamp" < '2003-01-01 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone))
         Buffers: shared hit=12
   ->  Index Scan using _hyper_1_138_chunk_weather_data_location_id_type_id_timestamp_i on _hyper_1_138_chunk  (cost=0.42..801.22 rows=205 width=16) (actual time=0.017..0.181 rows=168 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ((32 = location_id) AND (type_id = 1) AND ("timestamp" >= '2002-01-01 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone) AND ("timestamp" < '2003-01-01 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone))
         Buffers: shared hit=32
```

Production with `bitmapscan` off, same as developement:

```
 Custom Scan (ChunkAppend) on weather_data  (cost=0.42..36800.07 rows=9371 width=16) (actual time=0.033..11.086 rows=8760 loops=1)
   Order: weather_data."timestamp"
   Buffers: shared hit=1672
   ->  Index Scan using _hyper_1_137_chunk_weather_data_location_id_type_id_timestamp_i on _hyper_1_137_chunk  (cost=0.42..225.73 rows=55 width=16) (actual time=0.031..0.078 rows=49 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ((32 = location_id) AND (type_id = 1) AND ("timestamp" >= '2002-01-01 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone) AND ("timestamp" < '2003-01-01 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone))
         Buffers: shared hit=12
   ->  Index Scan using _hyper_1_138_chunk_weather_data_location_id_type_id_timestamp_i on _hyper_1_138_chunk  (cost=0.42..801.22 rows=205 width=16) (actual time=0.017..0.181 rows=168 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ((32 = location_id) AND (type_id = 1) AND ("timestamp" >= '2002-01-01 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone) AND ("timestamp" < '2003-01-01 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone))
         Buffers: shared hit=32
```

Production with `bitmapscan` on:

```
 Sort  (cost=30667.13..30690.56 rows=9371 width=16) (actual time=14.427..15.353 rows=8760 loops=1)
   Sort Key: _hyper_1_137_chunk."timestamp"
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 795kB
   Buffers: shared hit=1672
   ->  Append  (cost=5.26..30048.93 rows=9371 width=16) (actual time=0.044..11.541 rows=8760 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=1672
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on _hyper_1_137_chunk  (cost=5.26..202.75 rows=55 width=16) (actual time=0.043..0.089 rows=49 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: ((32 = location_id) AND (type_id = 1) AND ("timestamp" >= '2002-01-01 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone) AND ("timestamp" < '2003-01-01 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone))
               Heap Blocks: exact=9
               Buffers: shared hit=12
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on _hyper_1_137_chunk_weather_data_location_id_type_id_timestamp_i  (cost=0.00..5.25 rows=55 width=0) (actual time=0.029..0.029 rows=49 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((32 = location_id) AND (type_id = 1) AND ("timestamp" >= '2002-01-01 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone) AND ("timestamp" < '2003-01-01 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone))
                     Buffers: shared hit=3
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on _hyper_1_138_chunk  (cost=7.55..642.37 rows=205 width=16) (actual time=0.047..0.189 rows=168 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: ((32 = location_id) AND (type_id = 1) AND ("timestamp" >= '2002-01-01 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone) AND ("timestamp" < '2003-01-01 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone))
               Heap Blocks: exact=28
               Buffers: shared hit=32
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on _hyper_1_138_chunk_weather_data_location_id_type_id_timestamp_i  (cost=0.00..7.50 rows=205 width=0) (actual time=0.037..0.037 rows=168 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((32 = location_id) AND (type_id = 1) AND ("timestamp" >= '2002-01-01 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone) AND ("timestamp" < '2003-01-01 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone))
                     Buffers: shared hit=4
```

---

**Edit 2** Using a covering index.

```
create index on weather_data (location_id, type_id, timestamp, value);
```

```
                           Table « public.weather_data »
   Colonne   |           Type           | Collationnement | NULL-able | Par défaut 
-------------+--------------------------+-----------------+-----------+------------
 timestamp   | timestamp with time zone |                 | not null  | 
 location_id | integer                  |                 | not null  | 
 type_id     | integer                  |                 | not null  | 
 value       | double precision         |                 |           | 
Index :
    "weather_data_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (location_id, "timestamp", type_id)
    "weather_data_location_id_type_id_timestamp_value_idx" btree (location_id, type_id, "timestamp", value)
```

Indexes are now more than twice the table. I suppose I could use the new index in place of the PK.

```
SELECT * FROM hypertable_detailed_size('weather_data');
 table_bytes | index_bytes | toast_bytes | total_bytes | node_name 
-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------
 24146182144 | 53868445696 |           0 | 78014627840 |
```

The query doesn't seem to be faster:

```
 Sort  (cost=30671.13..30694.56 rows=9371 width=16) (actual time=31.547..32.394 rows=8760 loops=1)
   Sort Key: _hyper_1_137_chunk."timestamp"
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 795kB
   Buffers: shared read=1673
   ->  Append  (cost=5.26..30052.93 rows=9371 width=16) (actual time=0.125..28.312 rows=8760 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared read=1673
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on _hyper_1_137_chunk  (cost=5.26..202.75 rows=55 width=16) (actual time=0.123..0.265 rows=49 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: ((32 = location_id) AND (type_id = 1) AND ("timestamp" >= '2002-01-01 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone) AND ("timestamp" < '2003-01-01 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone))
               Heap Blocks: exact=9
               Buffers: shared read=13
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on _hyper_1_137_chunk_weather_data_location_id_type_id_timestamp_v  (cost=0.00..5.25 rows=55 width=0) (actual time=0.092..0.092 rows=49 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((32 = location_id) AND (type_id = 1) AND ("timestamp" >= '2002-01-01 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone) AND ("timestamp" < '2003-01-01 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone))
                     Buffers: shared read=4
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on _hyper_1_138_chunk  (cost=11.55..646.37 rows=205 width=16) (actual time=0.100..0.573 rows=168 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: ((32 = location_id) AND (type_id = 1) AND ("timestamp" >= '2002-01-01 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone) AND ("timestamp" < '2003-01-01 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone))
               Heap Blocks: exact=28
               Buffers: shared read=32
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on _hyper_1_138_chunk_weather_data_location_id_type_id_timestamp_v  (cost=0.00..11.50 rows=205 width=0) (actual time=0.079..0.079 rows=168 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((32 = location_id) AND (type_id = 1) AND ("timestamp" >= '2002-01-01 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone) AND ("timestamp" < '2003-01-01 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone))
                     Buffers: shared read=4
```

Comment: Did you generate the statistics after adding the new key?

Comment: We'd have to see the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for both queries. Do you get a different, faster, plan if you first `SET enable_bitmapscan = off;`?

Comment: Thanks @LaurenzAlbe. Question edited with elements you asked for.

Comment: In case that helps, the prod DB has 21 full years of hourly data (184104 rows) x 25/25 data types (temperature, humidity,...) x 101/101 locations. The dev DB has 1 full year of hourly data (8760 rows) x 25/25 data types for 1/101 location.

Comment: I'd say that both plans are very fast. I'd use larger tables to see if the optimizer is noticeably wrong. If anything, the `Custom Scan (ChunkAppend)` is overpriced - you might want to talk with TimescaleDB about that. But run a test wit larger tables first.

Comment: When connected to prod DB with CLI, the select for 1 year is instantaneous and for 20 years more like 2 seconds. Selecting in the CLI then pressing the "End" key to navigate to the last value is very fast. Is this the actual time taken to serve the query or is it shorter because it doesn't actually read all the data from DB (because I don't display it, just jump to the end)?

Comment: It's not uncommon to have indexes be larger than tables for this kind of time-series data. DBMS systems are all about time / space tradeoffs.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track with your BTREE index on `(location_id, type_id, "timestamp")`.

If you `INCLUDE(value)` in its definition, postgreSQL can treat it as a [*covering index*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/indexes-index-only-scans.html) and so use it to satisfy your query entirely without having to go back to the main table's heap.  That should help a lot.

Also, no need for it to be UNIQUE.  Your primary key index takes care of the uniqueness rule for you.

```
CREATE INDEX weather_data_location_id_type_id_timestamp_idx 
          ON weather_data 
       USING BTREE
             (location_id, type_id, "timestamp")
     INCLUDE (value);
```

Better yet, include the value in the index.

```
CREATE INDEX weather_data_location_id_type_id_timestamp_idx 
          ON weather_data 
       USING BTREE
             (location_id, type_id, "timestamp", value);
```

Then your index will be able to satisfy summarizing queries like

```
 SELECT DATE_TRUNC('month', timestamp) AS month,
        location_id,
        type_id,
        MAX(value) as high,
        MIN(value) as low
   FROM weather_data
  WHERE type_id = 1
    AND location_id = 31
    AND timestamp >= '2000-01-01' 
    AND timestamp < '2020-02-02'
  GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('month', timestamp), location_id, type_id
```

But of course, there's no magic that makes it particularly fast to process two decades` worth of weather data. postgreSQL's query planner may decide it's more efficient to satisfy such a broad query by scanning your whole table.  Try narrower date ranges.

And in toy-size tables it may be more efficient simply to slurp the entire table into RAM and scan it to satisfy the query. I personally have never had much luck trying to make sense of execution plans on toy-size tables.

Comment: Thanks for all the information. I added the covering index you describe, and strangely, it doesn't seem to help. See Edit 2. I was expecting an improvement, while still trying to understand how come an index essentially duplicating the whole table can be faster than table loop-up and why not drop the table at this point, or implement tables like indexes are implemented, but that would be another question, I guess.